# Sudo Error " you must have a tty to run sudo"

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, git, sudo

I am trying to run the following command:

```
sudo git pull;
```

I get the following error:

```
Command failed: sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo
```

The command is being run from a nodejs server using `child_process` and `exec`.

I have looked at other questions and sites that try and solve this error but none of the solutions ie editing `/etc/sudoers` and using `ssh -t` work.

I do not have root access and am therefore using sudo in the command.

I am running a basic Amazon EC2 Linux 64bit instance.

Comment: What did you try to edit `/etc/sudoers` with `visudo`? How about `ssh -t -t ...`?

Comment: @quanta - I tried to comment out the `Default requiretty`.

Comment: Did you try `ssh -t -t...`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your sudoers file (or have the administrator verify it).  It contains something that looks like this:

```
Default requiretty
```

(Default can also just be a group, easier to just search for requiretty)

The quick and easy is to comment this out, and this will resolve that problem.  You can also set it with !requiretty for the specific command.

You can also try calling sudo with --session-command to overcome this

Comment: Hi. I can only open /etc/sudoers as read only and cannot save any changes. Any ideas?

Comment: This is an EC2 instance.  I've never used one from the perspective of deploying/managing a VM on there yet, but I'm assuming there's some sort of console interface.  If you try from there, you should be assigned a TTY so you can get going.  I'm assuming here that you are an administrator but you simply don't have the password.  I don't feel like assisting in trying to do things you don't have permission to do ;)

Comment: This file is always read-only. You *must* use `visudo` to edit sudoers file.

Comment: visudo or not, he has no root access, and it seems he can't run commands with sudo, so he's still SOL.  You're right though, I was *assuming* (fatal error) that he was editing it with visudo, as it's very ill advised to do otherwise

Comment: @oker I still cant seem to save the edits when I use visudo. Any ideas?

Comment: @sandroid - I just don't have root access to the EC2 instance.

Comment: @Christopher, I believe you are SOL ;)  Get an admin to provide you with requisite access